# FirebaseJobDispatcher not start after reboot device

Tags: android, firebase-job-dispatcher

My FirebaseJobDispatcher not start after reboot device. I need the scheduler to start automatically after the device is rebooted.

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));

    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(ServiceAppControl.class)
            .setTag(AppGlobal.LOG_TAG)
            .setRecurring(false)
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 5))
            .setReplaceCurrent(false)
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
            .setConstraints(
                    // only run on an unmetered network
                    Constraint.ON_UNMETERED_NETWORK,
                    // only run when the device is charging
                    Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING
            )
            .build();
    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you add this permission into your manifest ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: can you try to increase the execution window for example .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(10, 40))